# Remove Custom Button from the Control Panel Menu

Tags: control-panel

I've created some menu buttons I no longer need, and want to remove them from the top menu of my ExpressionEngine control panel. Could someone please teach me how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you go to "My Account" in Control Panel you can see "Main Menu Manager" link under "Customize Control Panel". Follow that link and you'll see the list of your buttons. To delete a button, clear its name and submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

[Zoo Flexible Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin) has been one of my default add-ons when I set up EE just for this purpose. I typically move most of EE's menus & tabs under an "ExpressionEngine" tab, and then curate which tabs are available to the client.

You can apply those changes to Member Groups instead of setting them up as custom tabs per member

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark. Even though it's not quite something I was looking for, this is very useful in general.