# How to rename a tab?

Tags: control-panel

I've created custom tabs for the Channel entry form. Now, I want to rename it. The the toolbar for configuring the layout is open, I see a pencil icon to the left of my custom tab (as well as all the other tabs). When I click it, nothing happens. What am I supposed to see when I click that? Is that how I should be editing the tab name?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, I realized this is for custom publish layouts. This is not possible by default. A add-on will be needed, use [Rename Publish Tabs](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rename-publish-tabs) to accomplish this.

I'll add instructions too for changing the main menu tabs in case someone needs help in the future. To rename main menu tabs, click on your name in the CP (top right), then go to Main Menu Manger (left sidebar), you can rename your tabs there! You're limited to the custom tabs you created only. If you want to customize the entire CP menu, [Zoo Flexible Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin) is a great add-on.

Comment: Wait - but I created the tab. Are you saying that once it's created, it can't be renamed?

Comment: Yeah it's not possible by default. Either delete the tab and start over, or use that add-on above to rename

Comment: Oh, that's horrible. Then what is that pencil icon supposed to do?

Comment: Good question. Not sure why they have that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rename tabs. It's a system limitation. "Easiest" thing to do is create a new one and move your fields there. You can delete the old tab after.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5652/293), Zoo Flexible Admin may cover this and is great for customizing navigation & tabs in the Control Panel.